# Cant connect to a pc that uses static ip

Tags: windows-7, networking, router, ping

I have one workstation in our network that works strangely,
I do not know the exact terminologies, it uses a static ip which is configured in its local area connection properties. It can connect through our router and it can be seen in our router with its specific static ip..But the problem is we cannot ping the pc but it can ping itself and other pcs could not connect to it.we tried changing it to dynamic and adding an address reservation to it via router but still no light.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, got the answer and it is ridiculous..The firewall is on for public networks, tried to off it and it works

Answer (score 0):

Remove the static IP info from the adapter if not needed. If it is needed, enter the info on the router using the MAC address of the machine, instead. The IP address needs to be assigned by the DHCP service so it can be integrated into DNS and other services on the router.